# Flatten faces for plywood sheet cutting

Tags: faces

bit of a beginner here. I'm using Blender to design an electronic Cello. I want to flatten out the faces highlighted here so I can saw from a flat sheet of thin plywood which will then be wrapped to the 3D shape shown. I thought Mesh>Cleanup>MakePlanarFaces might work but sadly not. Any ideas?

[image: Cello perimeter]

Comment: flatten along which axis?

Comment: Thanks moonboots, but think I've answered it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think the Papercraft add-on sounds to be what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer. U (UV mapping) > S (Smart UV Project). Then with a bit of adjustment I get this, which seems to be what I want. Plus can export to SVG, using UVs>Export UV layout, which can then be imported as a mesh too. [image: Unwrapped]

Comment: I don't think that this will work. Blender's UV algorithm is kinda inaccurate and a "close guess" at a good result at best. I'd try one of the papercraft add-ons for Blender, if I were you. They are way more accurate for your purpose. There's also bad geometry in your mesh that needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks very much for that advice, as I say I'm a bit of a beginner here and slowly feeling my way.